# Why format is not working while appending zeros?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have to send the NOTIFICATION_NUM of type string with leading zero but it only returns the number i.e. 76, 77 etc and not the appending zeros.

```
  responseRecord.NOTIFICATION_NUM = string.Format("{0:000000000000}", responseRecord.NOTIFICATION_NUM); //padding with leading zeros
```

NOTIFICATION_NUM is of type string.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a [custom numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) on a string. This will not work because that format could be applied only to numbers.
To get a 12 characters string padded with zero characters and aligned on the left you need to use [string.PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft)

```
// As an example
responseRecord.NOTIFICATION_NUM = "10";
responseRecord.NOTIFICATION_NUM = responseRecord.NOTIFICATION_NUM.PadLeft(12, '0');
Console.WriteLine(responseRecord.NOTIFICATION_NUM);
```

The first parameter of string.PadLeft is the total length of the resulting string. So 12 means that you want a string with 12 characters, if there are less chars in the input string then PadLeft will add that char '0' before the original string until you have a 12 characters string.

Comment: if a number is like 1234 then would it replace the zeros?

Comment: @Stackyboy correct. That format string only works for numbers.